# What is the graphical significance of partial differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

We use partial differentiation in many formulae in Physics, as well as for finding the centre of a conic section by using del s/del x = 0 and del s/del y = 0. But what is the graphical meaning of partially differentiating a function with respect to a variable. Like differentiation has a geometrical significance, likewise, does *partial* differentiation too has some geometrical significance. Please answer ASAP as I have been dying to know the answer...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question could be improved if you could edit your post to include a fuller explanation of the graphical significance of *ordinary* differentiation. As it stands, your "conic section" explanation makes little sense, and we are left to make wild guesses of what you mean by "graphical significance".

Comment: Uh, sorry about that. It was my first time here. But what I meant to say was that what does it represent, as in does it represent the slope with respect to some variable like differentiation does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a function of two variables, $z = f(x, y)$, the partial derivative $\partial z / \partial x$ at $(a, b)$ represents the slope of the graph of $f$ if you are standing at the point $(a, b, f(a, b))$ and facing in the $x$-direction. Similarly, $\partial z / \partial y$ represents the slope of the graph of $f$ if you are facing in the $y$-direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: Another thing Annie... How does it give me the centre of a conic by just partially differentiating a function...

Comment: @ManojRana I think you're asking why this gives you, say, the vertex of a paraboloid. Imagine a paraboloid, positioned like an upside-down bowl. The vertex sits at the highest point, which is the point where the slopes in both the $x$- and $y$-directions transition from positive to negative. So at that point, both are momentarily zero! If you want more explanation, or I'm not understanding the question, it would be good to post a new question.